# Determine which process owns an flock'ed file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have a Bash script that runs in multiple processess concurrently.  The relevant portion looks like this:

```
flock /var/lock/my_lock my_command
```

Given that `/var/lock/my_lock` exists, is there a way to determine which process owns it and thus which one is executing `my_command`?

Comment: `fuser /var/lock/my_lock` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `lsof | "egrep /var/lock/my_lock"` should work

Comment: That's cracking a nut with a sledgehammer. `fuser` is the tool to be used.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `grep`, `lsof` will accept the filename as an argument.

Comment: fuser and lsof report all processes trying to adquire the lock, doesn't say which is actually running my_command

Answer (score 2):

`fuser -v /var/lock/mylock` will display the user, process ID, access and command.  I found [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-fuser-command) to be helpful in understanding `fuser`.