# how to determine which process/thread holds the flock

Tags: locking

When one or more processes/threads do an flock, how to determine who is currently holding the lock. 'fuser' on the file shows all the threads holding and waiting for the lock, not just the one who is the current lock holder.
related thread : [Determine which process owns an flock'ed file](https://serverfault.com/questions/508423/determine-which-process-owns-an-flocked-file)